# Iterate items in a list using a pattern?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm creating a program that prints out the music scale the user wants to use (i.e.  The C Major Scale) 
The Major Scale uses a semi-tone pattern which is `2 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 1`

I'm new, so am not sure what my other options are. Sorry for the ignorance!

```
keys = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]

i = 0
while i < len(keys):
    print(keys[i])
    i += 2


# Output after being run:

C
D
E
F#
G#
A#

# Expected output
C
D
E
F
G
A
B
```

I apologize if this is poorly explained.

Comment: I don't know much about *C Major Scale*, but you're printing only the items without cardinal (`#`), is this a pattern or just a coincidence?

Comment: It's the pattern. Say I wanted to use D Major instead of C Major. I'd start at D and use the pattern, which would give me: D,  E,  F#, G, A, B, C#

Comment: If it's a pattern, why not use `if not "#" in key` do something ? Sorry for my lack of musical qualities!

Comment: @PedroLobito Because it doesn't have to be C major. The OP posted that as an example only.

Comment: @Selcuk Ok, I understood what OP wants after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers here are largely correct, but will only work for the key of C.  If you were to start with any other note, your code would fail with:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is because starting from, say, `D` and following the increment pattern, you end up falling off the end of the `keys` array.  One way to solve this is to append the `keys` array to itself, like this:

```
selected_key = 'D'
keys = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
major_scale = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]

mark = keys.index(selected_key)
for inc in major_scale:
    print((keys + keys)[mark])  # <-- Here is where we double the keys array
    mark += inc                 #      to avoid falling off the end.
```

The above would result in:

```
D
E
F#
G
A
B
C#
```

Comment: Holy crapy I love you for your knowledge!! This was exactly what I needed : D

Comment: Do you mind explaining this? Sorry if it's too much to ask...I just want to understand why you did what you did! @larsks

Comment: I'm really just making the `keys` array look like `["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]`, so that if you start at, say, `D` and walk up a major scale, you can go past `B` and continue on to `C#` without running out of items.  This happens in the expression `(keys + keys)`; with lists, `+` appends the two lists together.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to keep the increments in an array themselves, and iterate over that:

```py
keys = # ...
steps = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]

i = 0
for increment in steps:
    print(keys[i])
    i += increment
```

If you wanted to start at a note other than C, you'd need to avoid "index out of range" errors by taking the remainder of `i / len(keys)`:

```py
# ...
for increment in steps:
    print(keys[i % len(keys)])
    i += increment
```

Comment: Wow thanks. That's pretty incredible. So what if i wanted to start at a different index than 0 (aka 'C'). What if I wanted to start at index 4 (aka 'E')?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, which I posted specifically to address that situation...

Comment: @larsks's approach would work, or you could just take the remainder of `i` divided by the number of keys. (I'll update my answer to include that.)

Answer (score 0):

You must define the pattern *somewhere* to achieve that. A list is a suitable data structure for that purpose, for example:

```
keys = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
pattern_major = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
i = 0
for p in pattern_major:
    print(keys[i])
    i += p
```

Now this will only work for C major as it will run out of keys if you start with a different key. To make it circular, try this (for D major, for example):

```
...
i = 2  # D
for p in pattern_major:
    print(keys[i])
    i = (i + p) % len(keys)
```